# Hover effect on dynamically added table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a table with a hover event on the table cells, that toggles a css class in the header cells.
If I add a row to the table dynamically, the event doesn't delegate to the newly added row. I read that if I use the `.on()` jquery method, then it should delegate to dynamically added content. But it doesn't.

```js
var table = $("table tr");

var cells = $("tr");
var headerCells = $(".col");

cells.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();
        headerCells.eq(cellIndex).addClass("column-hover");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();
        headerCells.eq(cellIndex).removeClass("column-hover");
    }
}, '.data');

var html = '<tr><td class="item">added row</td><td class="item">added row</td><td class="item">added row</td><td class="item">added row</td><td class="item">added row</td></tr>';

$(".add").click(function() {
  cells.last().after(html);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column-hover {
    color: white;
    background: #2196F3;
    z-index: 201;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add item</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col">header 1</th>
      <th class="col">header 2</th>
      <th class="col">header 3</th>
      <th class="col">header 4</th>
      <th class="col">header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="data">row 1, cell 1</td>
      <td class="data">row 1, cell 2</td>
      <td class="data">row 1, cell 3</td>
      <td class="data">row 1, cell 4</td>
      <td class="data">row 1, cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data">row 2, cell 1</td>
      <td class="data">row 2, cell 2</td>
      <td class="data">row 2, cell 3</td>
      <td class="data">row 2, cell 4</td>
      <td class="data">row 2, cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data">row 3, cell 1</td>
      <td class="data">row 3, cell 2</td>
      <td class="data">row 3, cell 3</td>
      <td class="data">row 3, cell 4</td>
      <td class="data">row 3, cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data">row 4, cell 1</td>
      <td class="data">row 4, cell 2</td>
      <td class="data">row 4, cell 3</td>
      <td class="data">row 4, cell 4</td>
      <td class="data">row 4, cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="data">row 5, cell 1</td>
      <td class="data">row 5, cell 2</td>
      <td class="data">row 5, cell 3</td>
      <td class="data">row 5, cell 4</td>
      <td class="data">row 5, cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I missing?

I have a fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ltcppvpy/

Comment: [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: `$(".add").click(function() {` use event delegation like `$(document).on('click','.add',function(){})`

Comment: @MLM, I guess `cells.on` is the issue..Try `$('table').on('your event','tr',callback)`

Comment: @RayonDabre delegation on document wouldn't work?

Comment: @MLM, element having class as `add` is not dynamically added, `tr` is added dynamically hence `$(document).on('click','.add',function(){})` is not the problem statement here.

Comment: Your current *event delegation* would work if you added new `.data` cells to `tr` - but you're adding a whole new `tr`.  When the `.on` is called, it attaches to everything in the selector (this case all existing `tr`s) - it does not attach to new `tr`s

Comment: Simple solution is: change your `cells.on` to `table.on({ ... }, 'tr .data');`

Comment: @freedomn-m I like your explanation. it also does work with `table.on({ ... }, '.data');` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appended `html`(variable `html`) doesn't have class `.data` so first you should add it in event selector list (`'.data, .item'`) and `cells` is not updated when you append an element to it so my suggestion is to use `$('body')` instead of `cells`(`cells.on` -> `$('body').on`).

Use the below code:
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltcppvpy/4/)

```
$('body').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();
        headerCells.eq(cellIndex).addClass("column-hover");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();
        headerCells.eq(cellIndex).removeClass("column-hover");
    }
}, '.data, .item');
```

Comment: @RayonDabre You should give me time to explain about my answer.

Comment: That's a correct answer, even surely better to delegate to `table` level and set `data` class to new added item, not `item`. BUT that's OP which is messing up his code, this answer fixes it. See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltcppvpy/7/

Comment: @alirezasafian, you could explain it while posting first instance of your answer.

Comment: It works! the `.item` class was a typo in the code, it should be `.data` as well